# How to do Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) in a scala play web application

Tags: windows, scala, authentication, playframework, ntlm

I've tried hard to familiarize myself with the different authentication protocols for Windows (NTLM v1, NTLM v2, Keberos, LDAP..) and based on that understanding I believe NTLM (v1/2) should be the target implementations.

I have a simple web application developed in Scala Play for which I would like it to have a login feature based on the AD credentials of a user (manual or through the existing workstation session).

That being said, I am struggling to get it to work. I found a few libraries on the web mostly poorly documented and others commercial only.

A simple example, or resource as to how to get it working would massively helpful.

Comment: Is it suitable for you to make a separate login page that would use login and password for LDAP authorization and if it succeeded to set special cookie and use it then?

Comment: Yeah that could work actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a try on [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/), sample codes as follows:

```
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.connTimeout", "1000");
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("domainControler"); 
        UniAddress myDomain = new UniAddress(ip);
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain_name", user_name, password);
        try{
            SmbSession.logon(myDomain, auth);
        }catch(Exception sme){
            //Login failed.
        }
```